# How can i catch the Recaptcha submission text in selenium

Tags: selenium-rc

This is my problem,I'm doing the automation test in selenium for Sign up a form, it has Recaptcha submission text,How can i enter they random text field in selenium. I'm using C#. 
Anyone can help me please.
Thanks in advance 
Sankar

Answer (score 1):

We use a special sequence of character agreed with development do deal with that, and of course is disabled in production :) You may also suggest development to offer you a backdoor to achieve that. In our QA environment we have a backdoor web application to deal with this special situations.